# infinite recursion in python3.3 setter

Tags: python, python-3.x, properties

Can somebody tell me why there is a recursion in the following code ?

```
class A:

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 0

    @property
    def a(self):
        print ("called a getter")
        return self.a

    @a.setter
    def a(self, value):
        print ("called a setter")
        self.a = value


class B(A):

    def check(self):
        a = 10


if __name__ == "__main__":
    bb = B()
    bb.check()
```

I have to call a base class setter from child class. I am not allowed to access the member directly. Can somebody tell me how to do other way ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
@a.setter
def a(self, value):
    print ("called a setter")
    self.a = value
```

When `self.a = value` executes, it calls your method `a(self, value)` again, which executes `self.a = value` again, which calls `a(self, value)`... etc.

The conventional solution is to have different names for the property and the underlying attribute. Ex. you can add an underscore to the front.

```
class A:

    def __init__(self):
        self._a = 0

    @property
    def a(self):
        print ("called a getter")
        return self._a

    @a.setter
    def a(self, value):
        print ("called a setter")
        self._a = value
```

Comment: Cannot put it any more clearly