# Python:@property decorator has Maximum recursion error

Tags: python-3.x, python-decorators

I am new to OOPS and testing property decorator. This is working fine with the string type but for an integer, it is failing with Maximum recursion error when property for age.Did anyone come across recursion code?. I have seen a post to add an object in the syntax for the class but it didn't help much.

```
class person(object):
    def __init__(self, first, last, age=0):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.age = age


    @property
    def e_mail(self):
        self.email = self.first+'.'+self.last+'@example.com'
        return self.email

    @e_mail.setter
    def e_mail(self,first,last):
        self.first=first
        self.last=last


    @property
    def age(self):
        return self.age

    @age.setter
    def age(self,age):
        self.age = age * 10


x=person('john', 'abc', 5)
print(x.first)
print(x.last)
print(x.e_mail)
print(x.__dict__)
x.first='jj'
x.age=10
print(x.__dict__)

Error message:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python/022618/test.py", line 30, in <module>
    x=person('john', 'abc', 5)
  File "C:/Python/022618/test.py", line 7, in __init__
    self.age = age
  File "C:/Python/022618/test.py", line 27, in age
    self.age = age * 10
  File "C:/Python/022618/test.py", line 27, in age
    self.age = age * 10
  File "C:/Python/022618/test.py", line 27, in age
    self.age = age * 10
  [Previous line repeated 493 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [infinite recursion in python3.3 setter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29539475/infinite-recursion-in-python3-3-setter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found some additional information on the stack overflow on the setter behavior and this works. This also explains why recursion is happening.
[infinite recursion in python3.3 setter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29539475/infinite-recursion-in-python3-3-setter?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Based on the suggestion, I have updated my code..Thank you for taking a look at it.

Here is the updated snippet

```
  @property
    def age(self):
        return self._age

    @age.setter
    def age(self,val):
        self._age = val * 10
```